# How many bytes are used for signed integer?

Tags: c, byte, data-representation

This is a code to display the hexadecimal and binary representations of integers and characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

void show_bytes(byte *bytes , int len)
{
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    printf("%-9.2X",bytes[i]);
}
printf("\n");
}

void show_binary(byte *bytes , int len)
{
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++) 
    {
        byte b = bytes[i];
        for(int j=sizeof(byte)*8-1; j>=0; j--)  
        {
            printf("%c" ,((1<<j)&b)?'1':'0');
        }
        printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
}
void show_int(int x)
{
    printf("Integer: %d\n",x);
    show_bytes ((byte *)&x, sizeof(int));
    show_binary ((byte *)&x, sizeof(int));
}
void show_string(char *x)
{
    printf("String: %s\n", x);
    show_bytes ((byte *)x, strlen(x));
    show_binary ((byte *)x, strlen(x));
}

int main()
{
    show_int (-5);
    show_string("abcd");
}
```

And the results of this code is as follow
[Code Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lygv5.png)
The question is how to read the result for both the interger and character, from my understanding the binary representation of -5 is

```
11111011 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

while for character 'a'  is

```
01100001
```

is it right? And is it stored in signed magnitude, one’s complement, or two’s complement?

Comment: Is not clear that `11111011` in binary the same as `FB` in hexadecimal?

Comment: The endianness and size of an integer varies across different architectures.

Answer (score 1):

> How many bytes are used for signed integer?

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(int));  // Often 4
```

Comment: do you know whether the representation is using signed magnitude, one’s complement, or two’s complement?

Comment: Becase `-5` shows as `FFFFFFFB`, this is clearly 2's complement.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your program output, it appears that your platform has 32-bit integers and is little-endian. So, being little-endian, the sequence `FB FF FF FF` means that the actual value of the `int` is `FFFFFFFB`, which is -5 in 32-bit 2's complement.

Comment: do you know whether the representation is using signed magnitude, one’s complement, or two’s complement?

Comment: Because `-5` shows as `FFFFFFFB`, this is clearly 2's complement.